# Terminal always displays wrong php version

Tags: php, terminal

I have installed php version 5.6.

When I run phpinfo() in browser it displays correct version but in terminal php version 5.3 is shown.

How can I solve this? Due to this problem I am unable to install laravel.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two programs:

- `php-cli` - what runs when you type `php` into your terminal
- `mod_php` - an apache module which runs PHP as a web server (could also be `fast-cgi` or another php module)

You need to update your `php-cli` (contact your web host if you don't control the machine).

Comment: how to do that locally?

Answer (score 1):

You have to also upgrade `php5-cli` package to get new version in terminal.

Also, there is separated `php.ini` files for both, webserver and terminal, versions.From default, you can find them in `/etc/php5/*`.